# Wrong default starting address

Tags: ollydbg, debugging

I have no idea how, when or why, but now, the "*default address*" (the one executed when pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>) is `0x77960884`. It should be `0x00401000` (when I manually go to `0x00401000`, everything works).

The problem is, I manually have to change the Origin every time I run *any* program.

Additionally, restarting Windows / reinstalling OllyDBG doesn't fix it. A few hours ago it was working fine, but now...

I have no idea.

Comment: Ollydbg > Options > Debugging options > Events (tab) > Make first pause at Entry Point of main module or WinMain. It sounds like System Breakpoint is your current setting.

Comment: Thanks for your idea! Unfortunately, this didn't work.. I have all default settings on ollydbg.ini since I reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is *somewhat* fixed.

This is not the same error I had, but [this plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873197/ollydbg-single-step-event-at-ntdll-press-shiftf8-to-pass-execution) fixed it.

PS: By "somewhat," I mean that some things definitely look weird / can't be used, but at least debugging works.